# Streaming live video, where to start?

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction. We have a few webcams that broadcast a live feed, but we want this live feed to be available on a website. Obviously security of the feed is ?important? and there are likely to be more than 1 person connecting at a time, so dont know if its best to use a 3rd party?

So my question is, what would people recommend to do the streaming? Would a 3rd party service be best to then pass the feed to the website? And once the stream is establish, how best is it to display the feed? Flash? HTML5? any recommend a player that will receive multiple live feeds?

Thanks for anyone who can point me in the right direction. I'm just unsure if its as simple as pointing to the IP of the webcam/computer or if theres more to consider with multiple feeds and hosting bandwidth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streaming architecture is somehow complicated, but it comes to this:

- you will capture video and deliver a stream to some 'distribution server'
- on distribution server, you'll setup a stream broadcast - then, you will have your stream address that points to the server 'distribution point'
- on the web page, you'll use media player such as Window Media Player, Silverlight smooth streaming player, or Flash player such as FlowPlayer to connect to the stream mentioned above to play it

To configure access rights you'll have to consult appropriate distribution server configuration.

If you choose Microsoft Smooth Streaming, start reading this: http://www.iis.net/learn/media/live-smooth-streaming/getting-started-with-iis-live-smooth-streaming

If you want to learn more about streaming in general, read about Shoutcast streaming, it's simple enough, but it will be only for learning, since it handles audio only (yes it has video too, but I didn't see it in practice).

Answer (score 0):

check out [flowplayer](http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html) it supports streaming. It's an open source flash based video player